# Ansible filter to find all lists with specified name

Tags: ansible

I have a task like

```
  - name: Verify all app states
    shell: get_cluster_states {{item.name}}
    register: service_states
    until: <all services are in 'up' state, this is what I need>
    retries: 20
    delay: 3
    with_items: "{{ apps }}"
```

The returned "service_states" has contents in format as below:

```
"service_states": {
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            ......
            "stdout": "Service Status: up\nService Status: up\nService Status: up",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "Service Status: up",
                "Service Status: down",
                "Service Status: up"
            ]
        },
        {
            ......
            "stdout": "Service Status: up\nService Status: up\nService Status: up",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "Service Status: up",
                "Service Status: up",
                "Service Status: down"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need filters to apply to the service_states data, so I can get a combined simple list from all "stdout_lines". In this case, totally 6 values from the 2 lists - number of list elements are not fixed:

```
expected: [
                "Service Status: up",
                "Service Status: down",
                "Service Status: up",
                "Service Status: up",
                "Service Status: up",
                "Service Status: down"
          ]
```

If I could achieve this, I'd be able to use unique/count/value to determine all services are up or not. I tried using {{ service_states.results | subelements('stdout_lines') }} to get the 6 entries, but don't know how to further filter out to get the final list as above.

Comment: Do you want to use *service_states* in the *until* statement?

Comment: Hi @VladimirBotka, yes, I need the _until_ work. First I tested your code with a debug after the task, it worked great. Then I used similar statements for _until_. But I got error `'dict object' has no attribute 'results'`. I thought maybe inside the loop there was no _results_ layer, so I changed code to `until: service_states.stdout_lines | unique | count == 1 and
       service_states.stdout_lines | unique == ['Service Status":" up']`. But this one is not evaluate to _Trues_. Is there a way to print out what the _service_states_ look like at the _until_ location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either *json_query*, e.g.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    expected: "{{ service_states.results|
                  json_query('[].stdout_lines')|flatten }}"
```

, or *map* attribute, e.g.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    expected: "{{ service_states.results|
                  map(attribute='stdout_lines')|flatten }}"
```

---

Q: *"**Determine all services are up or not.**"*

A: For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: All services are up.
      when: _all == _up
      vars:
        _list: "{{ service_states.results|
                   map(attribute='stdout_lines')|flatten }}"
        _all: "{{ _list|length }}"
        _up: "{{ _list|select('match', 'Service Status: up')|list|length }}"
            
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _all|int - _up|int }} services are down."
      vars:
        _list: "{{ service_states.results|
                   map(attribute='stdout_lines')|flatten }}"
        _all: "{{ _list|length }}"
        _up: "{{ _list|select('match', 'Service Status: up')|list|length }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 2 services are down.
```

---

Q: *"**Is there a way to print out what the service_states look like at the until location?**"*

A: No. There is no method to print the intermediate results. The task is running at the remote host. After the task completes the registered variable, *service_states* in our case, will be sent back to the controller. Instead, you can debug the module to see in detail what's going on. See [Debugging modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/debugging.html#debugging-modules).

---

Q: *"**Maybe inside the loop there was no results layer**"*

A: Yes. The results inside a loop are different. When the loop completes the registered variable must comprise the list of all results. See [Looping a task until it succeeds](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/OY5KSIdn0XQ/m/6LUXcOE4CAAJ)

---

Q: *"**Need the until**"*

A: Without the loop *until* works as described in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met), e.g. create the script below to generate random data

```yaml
shell> cat random.sh
#!/bin/bash
printf "Service Status: "
[ "$((1 + $RANDOM % 10))" -lt "5" ] && echo up || echo down
printf "Service Status: "
[ "$((1 + $RANDOM % 10))" -lt "5" ] && echo up || echo down
printf "Service Status: "
[ "$((1 + $RANDOM % 10))" -lt "5" ] && echo up || echo down

shell> ./random.sh
Service Status: up
Service Status: up
Service Status: down
```

Then, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    _pattern: "Service Status: up"
  tasks:
    - command: "{{ playbook_dir }}/random.sh"
      register: service_states
      until: service_states.stdout_lines|
             select('match', _pattern)|list|length == 3
      retries: 10
      delay: 1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ service_states.stdout_lines }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

TASK [command] **********************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: command (10 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: command (9 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: command (8 retries left).
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - 'Service Status: up'
  - 'Service Status: up'
  - 'Service Status: up'
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, this worked great! Thanks! But I still have a bit thing left on this, please see my response above to your 'until' question.

Comment: your _until_ condition worked great! Really appreciate your help! I'm all good now :)